# Do timer events get priority over I/O events in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

If there is some data to be read on the socket and if there is a timer that has elapsed, which callback will be fired first?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember the callback functions runs as follows:

1. process.nextTick() callbacks
2. Timers
3. I/O

But i can't find proof-link.